# Use Advanced Custom Fields to list a series of events

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I use the info put in here to display a list on the frontend?

[image]

The code I have so far (just to get things semi-functional):

```
<?php 
if( have_rows('imin_movie_times') ):
    while( have_rows('imin_movie_times') ) : the_row();
        $imin_movie_time = get_sub_field('imin_movie_time');
        $imin_repeats_every = get_sub_field('imin_repeats_every');
        $imin_how_many_times = get_sub_field('imin_how_many_times');
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
<p>
    Starts: <?php echo $imin_movie_time; ?> <br>
    Repeats Every: <?php echo $imin_repeats_every; ?> <br>
    <?php echo $imin_how_many_times; ?> Times
</p>
```

But what I need is a list of dates:

- August 8, 2017 12:00 am
- August 15, 2017 12:00 am
- August 22, 2017 12:00 am
- August 29, 2017 12:00 am
- September 5, 2017 12:00 am
- September 12, 2017 12:00 am
- September 19, 2017 12:00 am
- September 26, 2017 12:00 am
- October 3, 2017 12:00 am
- October 10, 2017 12:00 am

Comment: Put your paragraph code inside the while statement. It needs to be in the loop.

Comment: All you are doing is displaying the static values that were entered in the backend. I presume you're not asking us the logic behind working out what the list of dates are because that's not to do with writing code (and outside the scope of StackOverflow), so if you post the code you tried to create the list, we can help with the issues you are having.